# Direct construction of the integers

Tags: constructive-mathematics, lo.logic

> **Question.** Is there a direct construction of the integers which does not involve taking any quotients?

I am of course aware of the [usual construction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer#Construction).  I am also aware of the nice [axiomatic characterization](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23193/axiomatic-definition-of-integers) of the integers.

I am most interested in a **direct** construction.  I am sure that one could probably use a disjoint union of $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}^{+}$ to construct $\mathbb{Z}$.  But this involves 2 intermediate constructions (as well as dealing with cases).

**Edit.** By "direct construction", I mean something like the Peano construction for $\mathbb{N}$, seen as the inductive type built from $0$ and $\mathit{succ}$.  Then one also constructs the operations of addition, multiplication, etc.  Another way to think of it: suppose you wanted to have a datatype of "integers" in a lambda calculus which only allows inductive constructions and no quotients, how would you do it?

Comment: The free group on one generator?  

Or do you want to define multiplication, as well?  

Maybe you should provide an example of a "direct" construction of something else to show what you have in mind.


Comment: Strings of symbols, from a three-letter alphabet (representing digits 0, 1, -1; thought of as base 3 expansions).  All but finitely many digits must be zero.  Define operations essentially as in grade-school.  Is that what you want for "direct"?  I took balanced ternary, since you don't want to start with positive integers...



Comment: @Gerald: isn't your second construction 'redundant' (some numbers are multiply represented) so that you would need to take a quotient?  Yes, that is direct enough.

Comment: Balanced ternary doesn't seem redundant. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balanced_ternary Do you have a (counter)example?

Comment: You're fine as long as you eliminate trailing zeros, which I suspect is the objection.

Comment: I take my 'redundant' comment back - this seems to be a good answer. The only remaining difficulty are the leading zeroes (rather than the trailing zeroes) which would exist in a naive inductive definition of strings of symbols.  A 2-level definition can take care of that, though that is somewhat inelegant.

Comment: Ah sorry, leading indeed.

Comment: @Jacques: Defining Integers to be Maybe (Either Positive Positive) is also a 2-level definition (well it is once you combine Maybe (Either x x) into one level).

Comment: @Russell: indeed.  Seems unfortunate that there is not obvious, straightforwardly irredundant, elegant and direct *construction* of the integers.  [The initial object in the category of unital rings is certainly an elegant characterization!]

Comment: 0 (zero), S (successor) , P (predecessor)
Add the axioms PS(x)=SP(x)=x.

Comment: @Kaveh: those axioms induce a quotient.

Comment: How about using two types? One for non-negative integers and one for negative ones, each having one function and one constant.

Comment: Could you explain your motivation? Are you trying to get an efficient implementation of the integers, or something that works well in a proof assistant, or something that is mathematically elegant, or what?

Comment: @Andrej: a combination of the last two.  I want a quotient-free construction of the integers, as this is easiest to handle in all existing proof assistants, and is at the same time 'more elegant'.  It really does not feel like something as fundamental as the integers should require a 'complicated' construction.  A good representation should allow for proofs about properties of the integers which are 'structural', in the same way one easily gets structural proofs for most properties of the naturals, but  without reference to the naturals.

Comment: In that case, I would go for two-level inductive definition, followed by lemmas that show the thing has the correct universal property. Then you just keep proving everything from the universal property. Which leads to teh natural conclusion that you shouldn't really worry about how the integers are *constructed*, but rahter than *what they are*. Your proofs should not rely on any particular construction of the integers. That's my opinion.

Comment: I don't disagree!  I just wanted to "explore the design space" a bit more, to see what is possible.  

Comment: Maybe god gave us the natural numbers *and forced us to do some work* to get the integers?

Comment: @Gerald Edgar, you may insert your $(-1\ 0\ 1)$ construction into a separate answer. Then I will remove my copy.

Comment: Since the question is only about the **set** of integers: What's wrong with $\mathbb{Z} := \{0\} \cup \mathbb{N}^+ \times \{0,1\}$? Here $(n,0)$ means $+n$ and $(n,1)$ means $-n$.

Comment: @HeinrichD that is covered in the question: I would like something like an inductive type for $\mathbb{Z}$, which is constructed directly.  Yours is an indirect construction.  And I really should have asked about the ring of integers.

Comment: Wanted to use the fundamental group of the circle, but then realized this required quotienting by homotopy equivalence.

Comment: In the case of the integers (and this is well known) we can avoid a quotient by just redefining the operations to always produce a value in a particular set of representatives. For example we could define an integer to be a pair $(m,n)$ of naturals in which $m = 0$ or $n = 0$ - the set of such pairs is a selector for the usual equivalence relation used to define integers. Then we define the operations to always produce a result in our set. So the issue of having a quotient seems like it is a chimera. The same thing happens for the construction of $\mathbb{Q}$ from $\mathbb{Z}$, etc.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Informally speaking, taking the limit of [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) as the
number of bits goes to $\infty$,
the integers are just the eventually constant binary sequences (which
are naturally represented by finite binary sequences). 
For this to work, said sequences must start with the 
least significant bit, *i.e.,*
$1001011\overline{0}$ is interpreted as $2^0+2^3+2^5+2^6$ and
$1001010\overline{1}$ is interpreted as $2^0+2^3+2^5-2^7$.
The arithmetic and ordering of these strings is natural
(and efficient for microprocessors when we restrict
from $\mathbb{Z}$ to, say, $\{-2^{63},\ldots,2^{63}-1\}$).

The above can be reinterpreted as the following less direct construction. 
If $R$ is the inverse limit of rings
$\lim_{\infty\leftarrow n}\mathbb{Z}/2^n\mathbb{Z}$, then the diagonal map 
$\Delta\colon\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow R$ given by 
$m\mapsto \lim_{\infty\leftarrow n}(m\mod 2^n)$
is an injective ring homomorphism. [Edit: The image is characterized as the set of $\vec x\in R$ for which the truth value of $x(n+1)=x(n)$ is eventually constant.] Moreover, the ordering of $\mathbb{Z}$ is coded
via $m\geq 0\Leftrightarrow(m\mod 2^n: n\in\mathbb{N})$ is eventually constant.

**Update:** I couldn't resist the temptation to write a [functional programming implementation](http://codepad.org/BfuzCK5B).

Answer (score 13):

You could try [base -2 representations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_base), also called negabinary strings.  These are finite strings drawn from the alphabet $\{ 0, 1\}$, starting with 1 (except when zero or empty, depending on your choice of convention), where we weight places by powers of $-2$.  You have unique representations, and reasonably straightforward arithmetic operations.

Answer (score 3):

There is a paper by Fressola and Krone here [Integer Construction by Induction](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.304.5927) that seems to do what you want to achieve.

Comment: It definitely answers the question that I asked.  I guess I really wanted to ask for the result to have a more natural ordering.  More like balanced ternary.

Answer (score 3):

The group $\mathbf{Z}$ is the group of differences of the monoid $\mathbf{N}$, and the ring $\mathbf{Z}$ is the ring of endomorphisms of the (commutative) group $\mathbf{Z}$.

Comment: This is the usual construction, right?

Comment: What's a "group of differences"? The obvious constructions require a quotient.

Comment: Where "quotient" involves "equivalence" rather than a "division" :-)

Answer (score 3):

(was a comment, now an answer)...

Strings of symbols, from a three-letter alphabet (representing digits 0, 1, -1; thought of as base 3 expansions). All but finitely many digits must be zero. Define operations essentially as in grade-school. Is that what you want for "direct"? I took balanced ternary, since you don't want to start with positive integers...

Answer (score 2):

Is it not enough to modify Peano's construction? An idea (which is different from the onw linked by Iii) might be the following: Peano's construction makes use a function $succ(n)$ which verify the classical properties:

1. There is no $n$ such that $0=succ(n)$
2. $succ(n)=succ(m)$ implies $n=m$
3. If $0\in A$ and $succ(n)\in A$ for all $n\in A$, then $A=\mathbb N$

Maybe it is possible characterize $\mathbb Z$ making use of two (different) functions, $prec(\cdot)$ and $succ(\cdot)$, related by $prec(succ(n))=succ(prec(n))=n$. Of course, now the first property cannot be true, the second property above has to be required for both $prec$ and $succ$ and, finally, the third property has to be replaced with the following

**Induction on $\mathbb Z$:** If $A\subseteq Z$ contains at least one element and, moreover, for any $a\in A$ one has $prec(a),succ(a)\in A$, then $A=\mathbb Z$.

Should work.

Comment: This seems to be the same as what Kaveh suggested in a comment on the question.  The OP objected there that the axiom prec(succ(n)) = succ(prec(n)) = n induces a quotient.  That is, the integers will not be simply the terms built from succ, pred, and 0 but rather equivalence classes of such terms.

Comment: Andreas is correct: I was looking for a quotient-free construction.  And axioms 1-3 above are really another way of stating Goguen's "no junk, no confusion" axioms.

Comment: OK, sorry, I missed that comment. 

Answer (score 2):

I would say: the free group on one element. I guess you can translate this into a series of first-order axioms. Notice that multiplication comes for free as composition between automorphisms of the group with itself.

**Addendum**: Prompted by the comment below, I am not thinking about the usual *description* of the free group through a chain of $1$'s and $-1$'s but on the *universal property*.

Let me give some specifics. A group is a tuple $(G,m,e,i)$ with $G$ a set, $m \colon G \times G \to G$ a map $e \in G$ and $i \colon G \to G$ satisfying certain commutativities that amount to the defining properties of group (associativity, $e$ is the neutral element and $i(g)$ is the inverse of the element $g \in G$). A free group in one element is such a tuple $(F, \dot , 1, op)$ satisfying that for any choice of a $g \in G$ from a group $(G,m,e,i)$ there is one and only one homomorphism $(F, \dot , 1, op) \to (G,m,e,i)$ taking $1$ to $g$. I propose to translate this description into a series of first order formulas, that was my suggestion.

**Addendum 2**: I have just realized that this way the description is second-order.

Comment: But this still has quotients (eg $xy^{-1}y=x$) which is what the OP was trying to avoid.

Comment: @Richard Rast. Thanks for your comment. I didn't notice the first comment in the question either. However I wonder if there is a description of the free group that does not go through a quotient, something using the universal property.

Answer (score 1):

I provided a direct axiomatization of integers for instance under the MO question [Axiomatic definition...](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23193/axiomatic-definition-of-integers/) by @Victor Makarov, in the post [Part 2: Cyclands and integers](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23193/axiomatic-definition-of-integers/134770#134770). This axiomatization makes no direct reference to the natural numbers, or to any linear order.

Comment: Gerald Edgar already mentioned balanced ternary in a comment attached to the question.

Comment: @S.Carnahan, thank you for pointing to Gerald Edgar and his  $(-1\ 0\ 1)$ construction. Sorry for overlooking it at the time.

Comment: The $(-1\ 0\ 1)$ portion of my question got removed by me, it got replaced by the original answer by Gerald Edgar (got copied by him from his own earlier comment).

Answer (score 0):

We define a [formal language][1] as follows:

The free language $\mathcal J$ of all strings $J$ (words) in

alphabet : $R, L$

including the empty string, [].

This language comes naturally equipped with the concatenation operation,

$\tag 1 +: (J,J^{'}) \mapsto JJ^{'}$.

A string $M \text{ in } \mathcal J$ is said to be direct (or pure) if it does not contain both of the letters $R$ and $L$.

The strings $RL$ and $LR$ in $\mathcal J$ are called vis-à-vis steps.

If a vis-à-vis step is inserted anywhere into a string $J$, then the new output string is said to be an expansion of $J$.

If a vis-à-vis step can be removed from a string $J$, then the new output string is said to be a contraction of $J$.

Any string can be contracted to a direct string and can itself be obtained by expanding that same direct string. Two strings $J$ and $J^{'}$  are said to be homoJnic if $J$ can be be transformed into $J^{'}$ using expansions and contractions. When this is the case we can write $J == J^{'}$.

If $J_\alpha == J_\beta$ and ${J_\alpha}^{'} == {J_\beta}^{'}$ then $J_\alpha {J_\alpha}^{'} == J_\beta {J_\beta}^{'}$.

The addition of integers $\mathbb Z$ can therefore be defined as concatenation that is invariant under homoJnic transformations, each class being represented by a direct strings in $\mathcal J$.

Example: Adding two direct $RRRRR + LL = RRRRRLL == RRRRL == RRR$

Example: Since $RRRRR == RRLRRRR$ and $LL == RLLL$, we have
$\qquad RRLRRRR + RLLL = RRLRRRRRLLL == RRR$

Comment: It seems to me that the need constantly to perform contraction steps in order to do anything with these integers suggests that we are dealing with a quotient (of strings by the "homoJnicity" relation) in all but name.

Comment: (Specifically, see also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/29090/direct-construction-of-the-integers#comment77991_29090 and https://mathoverflow.net/a/80221/2383.)

Comment: @LSpice I wrote this up with the idea that a computer might understand it as constructive 'homotopy' math, and wouldn't have to understand set theory and partitions. I'm not a computer scientist - just taking a shot at it!