# A (second-order) axiomatic characterization of the integers which rules out surreal/hyperreal versions

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory, surreal-numbers

I've seen it stated, for example [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23193/axiomatic-definition-of-integers), that the integers are the *unique* commutative ordered ring with identity whose positive elements are well-ordered.

I understand why the integers are the *smallest* such ring, (and thus the initial object in the category of rings, for example), but why must they be the only one? In particular, why can't we have a commutative ring based on some larger well-ordered set? In particular, there are the "omnific integers" sitting within the surreal numbers, and presumably some hyperreal version of this as well. What I have in mind is some version of the [natural operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic#Natural_operations) on the class of ordinals, extended suitably (by the Grothendieck group construction perhaps, if the surreal number version doesn't work) to include additive inverses.

Why can't something like this work?

(Before you complain and say that surreals aren't a *set*, preventing them from being a ring, let's say that we define "the class of ordinals" by some suitable large cardinal or Grothendieck universe or something similar.)

**EDIT** As Wojowu pointed out in the comments, I'm probably over-thinking this: if $R$ is some commutative ordered ring whose positive elements are well-ordered, then there must be a map $f$ from $\mathbb{N}$ to $R$ by recursion (or initial-object stuff). Then, the set $X$ of all $x \in R$ which are greater than $f(n)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is either empty (in which case it's not hard to verify that $\mathbb{Z} \simeq R$), or has a least element $x$. Then $x -1 < x$, so we have a contradiction.

Maybe there *is* a set vs. class subtlety here? If we take the actual class of all ordinals, then $X$ won't be a set, so we need well-ordering for *sub-classes*. What happens if we only assume well-ordering for *subsets*? Does this sort of ambiguity ever matter, or are the integers *really* that unique?

Comment: If an ordered ring contains $\Bbb Z$ properly, then it contains either an element $\varepsilon$ between $0$ and $1$, in which case the elements $\varepsilon,\varepsilon^2,\varepsilon^3,\dots$ are positive elements and there is no smallest element of this set, or it contains an infinite positive element $\omega$, in which case you can take $\omega,\omega-1,\omega-2,\dots$ for the same purpose.

Comment: As for your last question, my above remark works for class-sized rings as well.

Comment: good point! If you'd like to put that up as an answer, I'd be happy to accept.

Comment: @dorebell: the issue with the example of ordinals isn't a set vs. class issue, it's that, as Wojowu's argument shows, requiring additive inverses breaks the well-ordering property.